# win32: Mutex is not freed fast enough?

Tags: windows, winapi, process, mutex

I recently stumbled upon some behavior that I can't really understand. Suppose I have an application that creates a named mutex object (we call this the "mutex app"): `CreateMutexW(NULL, FALSE, L"MyMutex_{2CFE84A4-FD69-462E-9291-2579BA52B5A1}")` and maintains a handle to that throughout the lifetime of the process, for the purposes of not letting other instances of the application run (this is achieved by the same call in a subsequent instance, which will set the last error to `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS`, thus indicating that there is already an instance of the application; after this, I ALWAYS close that handle and carry on).

Now, this question is not about whether this is a valid mechanism for detecting other instances of an application, I know already there are better/worse alternatives.

What I don't understand, though, is the following: suppose the application is started by another application ("the service app"), on a loop: it does `WaitForSingleObject` on the process handle returned by `CreateProcessW`, and then, recreates the process and so on. Basically, when the app that creates the mutex closes, it is restarted by some external agent immediately.

Now, what happens to me is that, if I kill the "mutex app" forcefully (with `TerminateProcess`, `taskkill /im`, from Task Manager etc), the "service app" just restarts it, but the "mutex app" then receieves `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS` when doing the `CreateMutexW`. Why? Because, as far as my understanding goes, the mutex should have just been freed by the OS, since its only user, the terminated "mutex app" no longer exists. That's not the case, it is still there. What is weird, is that it is eventually freed, but it just takes a while: if you terminate the new "mutex app" again, the subsequent one successfully creates that mutex just fine. Or, one can add something like `Sleep(1000)` before the mutex creation code, and, again, it works in the scenario described above.

So my question is: why? This looks like a bug to me, or idk, I can't find any official explanation for this. Shouldn't the OS atomically clean the structures of a process (be it terminated or clean exited) before letting others start, or something like that? Or is this intended behavior, and what's the reason, would it be too much overhead to create/terminate processes one at a time (serially)? And, is there any more professional workaround for this problem other than that naive `Sleep` call?

Thanks.

Comment: How is the service app detecting and restarting the terminated app?  Can you create a [mcve] for the monitoring code and app code?

Comment: Not letting any other processes start for the entire time it takes to terminate a process would be absolutely awful. Process termination is definitely not guaranteed to be atomic.

Comment: Why? There are only 295 processes on my system at the moment. What's the big deal in making that atomic? Processes start or stop VERY rarely anyway. A valid reason besides "parallelism is the way to go", "serial things suck" and "would be absolutely awful".

Comment: @MarkTolonen I do not have the exact code for that, that not being my app tehnically. I suppose is something like `while (1) { initialize_structs(&si, &pi); CreateProcess(&si, &pi, ...); WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE); CloseHandle(pi.hProcess); CloseHandle(pi.hThread); }`. Why does it matter anyway? The way I thought it's, a process exists, its handles should be dealt with by the OS before answering questions about them from others. If that's not the case, ok. But I also don't understand why it fails with `Sleep(100)` for e.g.? Does it take that long to free the proc info struct?

Comment: @MarkTolonen For creating the mutex and that logic I basically use this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/using-named-objects

Comment: @user1371019 For you to be able to rely on it, it would have to be a platform guarantee. The platform guarantee would also apply to 896 core systems. It would also cause all code in process termination to be performance critical. This requires, for example, bringing all process threads to termination-safe states. That would make a *lot* of code system performance critical and might even open up vulnerabilities where user code deliberately makes itself termination-unsafe as a denial of service attack.

Comment: How the monitoring app monitors could be important.  Why not create the mutex owned?  If the monitoring service ever owns the mutex, release it and spawn the app.  If it doesn't obtain ownership, wait for ownership which will be obtained when the app dies.

Comment: Please show a [mcve] that exhibits the issue. This isn't asking for *"the code"*. Feel free to start from scratch. The problem description suggests that either application is no more than a handful of lines of code.

Comment: Yeah, that would definitely work for the purpose stated above. But what I was more interested in why it takes so long for that to be freed. The scenarios I described is hypothetical, let's say. Also, this does not solve the issue of not letting someone else run another instance of the app if there's already one. I mean, I could try something like `TryAcquire` or whatever it is called in Window...

Comment: I tried three different implementations and can't reproduce your issue, so it is up to you to provide a [mcve], even if from scratch.  The point is *we* shouldn't have to create the code to reproduce the issue, but I was interested to see if I could.  It is just a few lines for the monitor and test app.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Me neither. Indeed, it works as intended standalone. What I have in practice is some DLL injecting Explorer by exploiting the DLL search order (my DLL is called `dxgi.dll`). The main body looks like this: https://gist.github.com/valinet/81f683d3779cf98f29dde622a5cc5261. Compile that as a DLL, name it `dxgi.dll` and drop it in `C:\Windows` and restart Explorer.

Comment: @MarkTolonen When it starts, it will spawn a console and show `NEW`. Close that console and then `winlogon` or `sihost` I think will start a new `explorer.exe`, which will still spawn a console but show `EXISTS`. That's the actual thing I do not understand. Indeed, idk exactly how this new `explorer` is spawned.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Can you reproduce this?

Comment: @SimonMourier Why? It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @SimonMourier ok

Comment: yes, i confirm that `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS` stable reproduced if kill *explorer.exe*. and if set small delay (*Sleep*) error is disappears. however you can make your dll much more simply - not need any code for export original api, if you not want hook it call. possible use forward export to original dll - https://pastebin.com/Dp6sJgEW

Comment: Aha, okay, I understand, did not know about that mechanism, thanks. And thank you for the testing and report as well. The behavior is very weird, I am not saying it is a bug, I just want to understand it, if possible. By the way, the provided pastebin example is great, will keep that for future reference and use ;)

Comment: this code - https://pastebin.com/YyxXaCpH with really use mutant and `CREATE_MUTEX_INITIAL_OWNER` effective work. but also return `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS` initially and `STATUS_ABANDONED` than.. however this really interesting, why mutant still exist when old process already terminated and new started (this of course take some time)

Comment: also i for test run this code - https://pastebin.com/GZQ8w5Az - i by self create process, which direct create named object (mutant, event - not play role). and then wait for process exit and just after this try recreate named object . and this is ok. no error ( ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS ) - so object really deleted after process is full terminated

Comment: so your assumption is wrong - mutex, or event will be free syncronous before process exit. but you also wrong how winlogon wait for shell. it not wait for shell process exit via `WaitForSingleObject` but set some alpc port for shell. when shell terminated - message is received by winlogon. at this point shell process still exist as object. `I_WMsgkSendMessage` called inside winlogon, then `ULONG WLGeneric_ShellRestart_Execute(StateMachineCallContext *)` which call `CreateProcessAsUserW`..

Comment: @RbMm Thank you, makes sense; it had to do some other stuff. Thanks for taking the time to check out and investigate this!